# Streaming Kafka with Python :kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have tried [this tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/#install-java) and have successfully consumed kafka topics that are published on a server at my work place. I am not the producer, just purely a consumer. However, the code in that tutorial is to stream in a terminal. Now I want to try it with Python and record the messages into text file (or something of that sort).

This is the code I use, after reading a few more threads and tutorials (such as [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-kafka-in-python-604b3250aa05)):

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

bootstrap_servers = ['xxxxxx:xxxx']
topicName: = 'my_topic_name'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName, group_id='group1', bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, consumer_timeout_ms=1000)

for msg in consumer:
    print(msg.value)
```

Here I want to first print out the message. But I get this error after 1000ms timeout:

```
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

which sounds logical to me, since a broker is needed and the code above does not seem to do anything with a broker.

If I don't set the `consumer_timeout_ms=1000ms`, the Python console get just stuck without displaying anything.

How do I resolve this?

***More details***:
I am doing the following in parallel:

1 - Run zookeeper in one terminal

2 - Run kafka cluster in another terminal

3 - Streaming the topics (nicely) in another terminal with the command `kafka-consumer-console`

4 - In another terminal, run the Python code in this question.

All of these terminals are Ubuntu in WLS2 (Windows).

Comment: _stuck without displaying anything_ - Because your topic has nothing producing to it... maybe? _the code above does not seem to do anything with a broker_ - yes it does, `bootstrap_servers`. Sounds like you have a network misconfiguration or you gave the wrong address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to use the WSL terminal with `kafka-console-consumer`, then running Python code *there* should work the same.

If you're connecting to a remote Kafka server, chances are the WSL2 network settings are simply not able to reach that address. (multiple issues elsewhere talk about WSL2 and not having external internet access) . Therefore, you should really consider running Python code on the Windows host itself. Otherwise, sounds like you'll need to adjust your network configurations.

---

The for loop will wait for **new** messages to a topic, not read existing data until you add another parameter to the consumer to tell it to

---

FWIW, you can use `kafka-console-consumer ... >> file.txt` to write out to a file

Comment: @OneCricketeet Thanks for responding. I have updated my question. When the messages arrive at the ```kafka-console-consumer```, I can see them nicely. But I get the ```No broker``` error on the terminal that runs the Python code.

Comment: So, what are your bootstrap servers? `localhost:9092`? And you run the Python code in the exact same terminal as the console consumer command? and use the same bootstrap servers?

Comment: It's a DNS name: 9093. The same for both Python code and ```kafka-console-consumer```. They are on two separate terminals: one runs console, one runs Python.

Comment: Kafka doesn't run anything on port 9093 by default, so what did you change?

Comment: That's the server and port address where the data is being streamed at my work place. I am not doing anything on the ```producer``` side.

Comment: If you are trying to communicate with a completely remote server, you should run the code on the Windows host, not in a Linux hypervisor. Especially if you need some VPN or other networking setup to communicate to your company servers

Comment: I am still unable to run the Python code. But your ```>> file.txt``` suggestion works for me on the ```kafka-console-consumer```. I am marking this as closed.