# Kafka consumer/producer with Python in WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: python, apache-kafka, wsl-2

This is a follow-up question from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893882/streaming-kafka-with-python-kafka-errors-nobrokersavailable-nobrokersavailable).

As per advised from the thread, the possible cause for why my Python code is not working is because I was to connect to a remote server in WSL2. And there could be unknown issues with WSL2 Ubuntu.

So I am testing that hypothesis with the following two approaches of communicating within WLS2 Ubuntu locally (i.e. via `localhost:9092`):

Note that, for both approaches below, I already have zookeeper running in one terminal (`T1`) with:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Approach 1**: communicating with producer/consumer in console as described by the following commands (taken from [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-20-04))

*Step 1*: create a topic `TutorialTopic` (in terminal `T2`)

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TutorialTopic
```

*Step 2*: produce a message in a terminal `T3`

```
echo "Hello, World" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic
```

*Step 3*: consume the message in another terminal `T4`

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning
```

***Outcome***: I see a message `Hello, World` in terminal T4

**Approach 2**: communicate through two Python modules, `consumer.py` and `producer.py` as in [this tutorial](https://timber.io/blog/hello-world-in-kafka-using-python/):

*Step 1*: create a topic `sample` in terminal `T5`

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic sample
```

*Step 2*: run the producer module in terminal `T6`

```
producer.py
```

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
producer.send('sample', value='Hello, World!')
```

*Step 3*: consume that message in terminal `T7`

```
consumer.py
```

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('sample', bootstrap_servers=['localhost: 9092'])

for message in consumer:
    print (message.value)
```

***Outcome***: Nothing is displayed on `T7`. The Python console is stuck in the run unless I execute `Ctrl+C`. No other errors or messages are produceds. Unlike the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893882/streaming-kafka-with-python-kafka-errors-nobrokersavailable-nobrokersavailable) where I get `No Broker` error.

However, within this Approach 2, if I produce the message through a command in `T6` as following, I surprisingly receive it in the consumer terminal `T7`:

```
echo "Hello" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic sample
```

My ultimate goal is to consume the messages by Python app from a remote server and work with WSL2 Ubuntu. This experiment seems to imply WSL2 is not the issue. If someone could enlighten as to what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> produce the message through a command ... I surprisingly receive it in the consumer terminal T7

No surprise here since you've not called `producer.flush()` or `producer.close()` in your Python producer app *after* starting the consumer loop.

The console producer blocks on every record by calling get() on the future - [source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L69), effectively flushing its buffer

Alternatively, you are missing the matching option for `--from-beginning` in the Python consumer if you wanted to see the previously sent records

---

Ultimately, testing a local client/server within the same network adapter/subnet isn't going to help resolve an external network connection

Comment: I get that. In this thread, I am trying to understand why Python consumer does not receive anything from the Python producer locally. I got two problems here: why sending and receiving in Python is not working; and why receiving from remote server with Python is not working.

Comment: `producer.send()` works after you send enough records in a batch. Messages aren't sent immediately. You can flush to force a batch to be sent. Regarding the remote server things, that I do not know

Comment: @Thanks for explaining. I got the Python producer and consumer to work (by sending 100+ messages and ```producer.flush()``` and setting auto_offset_reset='smallest'), based on your answer above. Will close this.